# Char from Byte Array in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

Is this the correct way to bit shift into a char?

```
char value = (char)((array[offset] << 9) + (array[offset + 1]));
```

If not, please correct me.

Comment: Probably it should be `<< 8` instead of `9` if I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually bit shifting into an unsigned short, but as there's no such thing in Java ME, a char would probably do the job even tho it's really ugly.

Comment: `array` is a byte array?  It sounds like Tagir just gave you the answer.

Comment: That's right. It appears that's the case. Hum... the shifting is maybe correct, it's more likely that the bytes is corrupted...But, I guess that Tagir is shifting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bytes in Java are a bit tricky.
They don't go from 0 to 255 like you might be used to from other languages. Instead, they go from 0 to 127 and then from -128 to -1.

This means, that all bytes in your `byte` array that is below 128 will be converted into the **correct** `char` with this code:

```
char value = (char)((array[offset] << 8) + (array[offset + 1]));
```

But if the `byte` value is above 127, you'll probably get results you didn't expect.

Small example:

```
class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte b = (byte)150;
    char c = (char)b;
    int i = (int)c;

    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(i);

  }
}
```

Will output this:

```
-106
ﾖ
65430
```

Not exactly what you might expect. (Depending of course how well you know Java).

So to properly convert 2 bytes into a char, you'd probably want a function like this:

```
char toChar(byte b1, byte b2) {
  char c1 = (char)b1;
  char c2 = (char)b2;
  if (c1<0) c1+=256;
  if (c2<0) c2+=256;
  return (char)((c1<<8)+c2);
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly I didn't found this information in any references, or maybe I didn't search enough.

Comment: It's supposed to be common knowledge for any Java coder, but I fell for it too and had big trouble when using a byte array for my game-levels, and spent a long time figuring out what was going on. :-)